# MySQL Cumulative Sum for JOIN of TWO TABLES stored in a VIEW

Tags: mysql

I have a view, which is a join of two tables and I need extra column in that view - cum_profit.

I got one solution, which does it for me, but I can't save it as a view, because "View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause".

That's the code: 
Note: cumulative_profit is the VIEW

```
SELECT *, cum_profit
FROM cumulative_profit
INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT match_id,
    @cum:=@cum+profit as cum_profit
        FROM cumulative_profit
        JOIN (SELECT @cum:=0) init
    ORDER BY match_date, ko_time, match_id
    ) cum USING (match_id)
ORDER BY match_date DESC, ko_time DESC, match_id DESC;
```

[Tables and view](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=31751555689107747940)

I tried to use other suggested ways for calculating the cumulative sum e.g. using similar code to this:

```
 SELECT t.id,
         t.count,
         (SELECT SUM(x.count)
            FROM TABLE x
           WHERE x.id <= t.id) AS cumulative_sum
    FROM TABLE t
ORDER BY t.id
```

But I failed to make it work with my tables and view.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should be equivalent to the first statement (assuming `match_id` is unique) and work in a view:

```
SELECT cp.*, 
       (SELECT SUM(cp2.profit)
        FROM cumulative_profit cp2
        WHERE (cp2.match_date < cp.match_date) OR
              (cp2.match_date = cp.match_date AND cp2.ko_time < cp.ko_time) OR
              (cp2.match_date = cp.match_date AND cp2.ko_time = cp.ko_time AND cp2.match_id <= cp.match_id)
       ) as cumulative_profit
FROM cumulative_profit cp
ORDER BY match_date DESC, ko_time DESC, match_id DESC;
```

Comment: This query has subquery, so you may not be able to create view from it

Comment: Thank you. MySQL Returns... 
#1051 - Unknown table 'cp' 
I had the same issue when tried to do what you suggested. Will it work in a view though?

Comment: @PiniCheyni . . . The limitation on subqueries is only in the `FROM` clause.